# Expression of gratitude

Tags: single-word-requests

conveying appreciation at times has no words. therefore how to begin this expression without having to say repeatedly the following sentence: There *are no words* to express...."

Comment: Are you speaking or writing a letter? And is the issue that you want to express gratidute nevertheless, and just want an altrenate beginning to “Words can not express but...”

Comment: *...no words to express...* is a popular and strong idiom which is better than any single word substitution.

Answer (score 0):

**I am overwhelmed by your generosity...** (or “by your kindness/support/whatever”)

Be careful though, becuause overwhelmed itself has connotations of being associated wth negative emotions like grief or sadness or of being overwhelmed with work. This idiom turns it around.